# How to use only Leaderboards feature and not achievements?

Tags: android

I need to use Google Play services Leader-boards but not the achievements. How to do i use only the Leader-boards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have to implement 6 achievements to be able to publish the game. If you don't want them, just declare them hidden and don't include a link inside the app.